# Remove entire row based on match?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, multiple-columns

Need to remove multiple rows within a CSV file in Excel based on a match in column L on sheet1 with column A on sheet2.  The content is email addresses.  How can I achieve this?

So, if sheet2 column A has an email address that matches any of the email addresses in sheet1 - Column L, than it should remove the entire row from sheet1 where that email address is located.

Sheet1 below:
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2 below:
[image: Sheet2]

@mehow, here's the image I get when I run your code as a module:
[image: Error with mehow's code]

Comment: Umm, You can use Autofilter?

Comment: How to use Autofilter?

Comment: You can see the Autofilter Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, very fast for what you are looking to do as it doesn't involve ANY loops.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()

Dim StartingScreenUpdateValue As Boolean
Dim StartingEventsValue As Boolean
Dim StartingCalculations As XlCalculation

With Application
    StartingScreenUpdateValue = .ScreenUpdating
    StartingEventsValue = .EnableEvents
    StartingCalculations = .Calculation
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


Dim varTestValues As Variant
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

With sh2
    varTestValues = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

sh1.Range("L1", sh1.Range("L" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(varTestValues), Operator:=xlFilterValues

sh1.Range("L2", sh1.Range("L" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

sh1.AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = StartingScreenUpdateValue
    .EnableEvents = StartingEventsValue
    .Calculation = StartingCalculations
End With

End Sub
```

***NOTE:*** This code runs assuming your data has headers if it does not please advise.

***REMEMBER*** Always run any code on a copy of your data and not your actual data until you are confident that it is working 100%.

Comment: Where do I put this at?  Yeah, I have headers in both sheets that take up the first row.

Comment: Added this as a macro and ran it and This removed everything in sheet1, and sheet2 stayed the same.

Comment: And your are 100% positive that not all values in sheet1 are on sheet2? I tested this code about a dozen times and it ran fine. Does your data already use filters?

Comment: No, both of these sheets were imported from CSV files.  No filters.  Sheet1 Column L has over 6,000 unique email addresses, and Sheet2 Column A only has 947 unique email addresses.

Comment: Alos if you have more columns in your data then just L that are contiguous you will have to change the Field value from 1 to the column that L represents (if the first column of your data is in column A then change the field to 12)

Comment: If you don't change the field then what it is doing is filter column A (field 1 of your Data) for values that are in Sheet2 Column A.

Comment: Added images of both sheets now.

Comment: @SolomonClosson I changed my code to reflect your images see if that works, I changed the field in the autofilter to field 12 to reflect Column L.

Comment: I get error again on Autofilter, and highlights this line here:  `sh1.Range("L1").AutoFilter`  I am using the code within a module, is that correct?

Comment: That line is to just turn off the auto-filter, try and comment it out and see if your data looks fine, it might not need that line.

Comment: Yeah, I believe this actually worked!!!  Error occurred, but it seems to have filtered all email addresses in Sheet2 Column A out of Sheet1 Column L, and removed the rows!!!  THANKS SOOO MUCH!