# Deleting worksheets by macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all sheets except the first sheet, but I get an

> error 9 "subscript out of range" appears.

How can I fix it?   Thanks in advance.

```
Dim Udalenie As Integer 
   If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
      For Udalenie = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Udalenie).Delete
   Next Udalenie
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because each time you delete one sheet, the Excel will remove it from this sheet from Worksheets and the total sheets count will minus 1.

```
Dim Udalenie As Integer
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
For Udalenie = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Delete
Next Udalenie
End If
```

Comment: I need to delete all sheets except first one. How could your answer help, this code deletes only 2 sheet.

Comment: @Seya have you tried this code? It doesn't only delete the 2nd sheet. There is a loop set up to run multiple times => sheets.Count ( so if you have 5 sheets the loop will run 4 times ). And each time the loop runs it deletes the 2nd sheet. See explanation of shifting indexes [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265508/how-to-select-and-delete-every-3rd-column/19265852#19265852)